# Can't left align a JLabel within a JPanel when adding to a BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, boxlayout

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't get it to work.

I have a `BorderLayout`. I want to use the top part for a title bar. I  want to add a `JPanel` with labels, buttons and other components. However, the `PAGE_START` part of the border layout won't left align the panel. Here's the situation, with comments in where I've tried to set the alignment.

I noticed that when I don't add a panel to the border layout, and just write the `JLabel` straight in, it has left alignment by default.

This is not what I want, though, because I am planning on putting a `BoxLayout.X_AXIS` horizontally through the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` title area. Seems to be a reasonable thing to do?

The `Container` pane argument to the static method is just the single panel on the main `JFrame`.

```
public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) 
    {
        JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("I want to left align this inside a JPanel");
        // Doesn't work: jlabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        //Doesn't work: jlabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        jpanel.add(jlabel);
        pane.add(jpanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        // Other parts of the BoxLayout (works fine)
        JButton button = new JButton("Button 2 (CENTER)");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        pane.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Button 3 (LINE_START)");
        pane.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4 (PAGE_END)");
        pane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        button = new JButton("5 (LINE_END)");
        pane.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }
```

Even when I tell the panel to left align the label, it doesn't appear left aligned.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default a JPanel uses a `FlowLayout` with "center" alignment.

if you want components "left" aligned, then you need to set the layout on the panel to use a `FlowLayout` with "left" alignment.

Read the `FlowLayout` API for the proper constructor to use to set the alignment.

Or you can also read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use FlowLayut](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) which gives the constructors and valid values to specify the alignment.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer the clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I am not using FlowLayout in the JPanel. Like I mentioned, the JPanel has BoxLayout, and regardless of the alignment I apply to a JPanel containing a BoxLayout, the JLabel aligns to the centre.

Comment: @bluejazzshark *I am not using FlowLayout in the JPanel.* - based on the code provided yes you are. What part about my first sentence is not clear? I only see one JPanel created in the code. Where do you change the layout manager of the panel to use a BoxLayout??? Our comments can only be based on code that is posted. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem is you think you are using a BoxLayout.